# For loop won't iterate

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I have a function which works perfectly, until I stick it in a for loop - at which point I get a reference error (can't find i) in Safari. In Chrome and Firefox it runs but only for the first iteration (i.e. for i = 0). What's going on?

EDIT: The point of the for loop here is to iterate when the function within it (including the time-out) is complete. If anyone has an alternative suggestion for how to do this that would be great.

The function without the for loop:

```js
let realScores = [40,7, 3, 2]
let scores = [0,0,0,0]
  
  let i = 0
  let counter = 0
  function timer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      scores[i]++
      console.log(i, scores[i])
      if (scores[i] < realScores[i]) {
        timer()
      }
    }, 10)
  }
  timer()
```

And with the for loop:

```js
let realScores = [40,7, 3, 2]
let scores = [0,0,0,0]

for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  let counter = 0
  function timer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      scores[i]++
      console.log(i, scores[i])
      if (scores[i] < realScores[i]) {
        timer()
      }
    }, 10)
  }
  timer()
}
```

Comment: You are defining a new `let i = 0` within the loop's body which hides the `i` defined within the loop definition. Ie the `i` in line 4 of your code and the `i` in line 9 of your code are two different variables. So of course any reference to  `i` inside your loop's body will be `0`

Comment: Ups, that was just an error when adapting my code for uploading here. Corrected now. The problem persists as before in Safari. In other browsers it works though not as expected. I'm trying to get the for loop to iterate after the timeout function is complete.

Answer (score 0):

For loops are synchronous and that means they will execute before the `setTimeout` completes - you can't stall the execution of the for loop to wait for the resolution of the `setTimeout` callback.

Luckily, you can use `Promise`s and `async`/`await` to block the execution of the for loop to wait for the `setTimeout` to resolve:

```js
let realScores = [40,7, 3, 2]
let scores = [0,0,0,0]

function timer(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const t = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        scores[i]++;
        console.log(i, scores[i])
        if (scores[i] < realScores[i]) {
          t();
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      }, 10);
    }
    t();
  }); 
}
(async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  let counter = 0;
  await timer(i);
}
console.log(scores);
})();
```